# Python: How to send message to client from server at any time?

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I'm building a discussion board style server/client application were the client connects to the server, is able to post messages, read messages, and quit.

See client code below:

```
import socket

target_host = "0.0.0.0"
target_port = 9996

#create socket object
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#connect the client
client.connect((target_host,target_port))

#receiving user name prompt
print client.recv(1024)

usrname = str(raw_input()) 

#send username
client.send(usrname)

#check if username was unique
while client.recv(1024) == "NU": #should exit once "ACK" received
    print client.recv(1024) #print username promt again

    usrname = str(raw_input()) #client enters in another username
    client.send(usrname)

#receive user joined message/welcome message/help menu
response = client.recv(1024)
print response

print client.recv(1024)

#loops until client disconnects
while True:

    request = str(raw_input("\n\nWhat would you like to do? "))
    client.send(request)

    if request == "-h":
        help_menu = client.recv(1024) 
        print help_menu

    elif request == "-p":
        #get subject
        subject_request = client.recv(1024)
        print subject_request

        subject = str(raw_input())
        client.send(subject)

        #get contents of post
        contents_request = client.recv(1024)
        print contents_request

        contents = str(raw_input())
        client.send(contents)

        #get post notification 
        message_post = client.recv(1024)
        print message_post

    elif request == "-r":
        #get id value of post 
        id_request = client.recv(1024)
        print id_request

        message_id = str(raw_input())
        client.send(message_id)

        #get contents of post 
        message_contents = client.recv(2048)
        print message_contents

    elif request == "-q":
       break
    else:
        print client.recv(1024)
```

When a client joins though, I wish to notify all other clients that are connected that a new client has joined, but each client may be at a different point in the code (some may be in the middle of a post, sitting idle at the "what would you like to do?" statement, etc).

So how would I set my client code up that it will be able to accept a message from the server the moment another client joins?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. Here an overview of how I would.

Are you familiar with ["select"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) operations? They allow you to listen on multiple file descriptors and get notified whenever one becomes active. I would start by using that to both listen for keyboard inputs and server messages.

Then there are 2 things to be done. Branch depending on the active canal. If it's a keyboard input you can relay the command to the server. If it's a server message, you need to branch again on the message type to act accordingly.

Edit: Never assume what the server message is about. Even though you may have just sent a query, the server may be sending data about something else.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that operation, but I'll read into it and try to figure it out. From what you've said, that is exactly what I was hoping to do. Thanks!